# How to set up custom domain name

Tags: fedora, apache-httpd

Hello I have a Fedora 21 server OS and I would like to host a website on it. How can I configure my customised web address for example isaacme.com. I am using Apache!

Answer (score 1):

If you have one site, which you want to support on your machine, it is not necessary to configure(of course if you have a DNS record). But to answer on your question, you can put your domain name in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
ServerName: isaacme.com
```

And in your host file, /etc/hosts:

```
"your ip address"    isaacme.com
```

Comment: Does this make the web domain public i.e it could be accessed from networks other than the one it is hosted on?

Comment: To see the domain from another computer(public) it must have a DNS record which point to your web server(your public IP address). If you buy your hostname from hosting company it should have DNS Server and there you can put your ip.